# Need a trigger on User which makes Custom object sync with User object on the basis of common field email

Tags: apex, trigger

Want to sync the User object to get sync with custom object with a trigger on "User".
There is a field of Lookup(with User object) type in my Custom object(Employee__c) named as "user"
Like if i create or update a user a new custom object(Employee__c) record get created or updated respectively.
below is the fields of my Custom object(Employee__c)
Fields[image] of my Custom object(Employee__c)

I have started with this but got lost . It Would be great if get the right trigger for this.

```
trigger SyncUserToEmployee on User (before insert , after update) {

     Set<String> existingemails = new Set<String>();
    Set<Id> existingids = new Set<Id>();

For(User usr : Trigger.new){

    existingemails.add(usr.Email);

}
Employee__c emp = new employee__c();
for(String email : existingemails ){

    emp.Email_Id__c = email;
    emp.Phone_Number__c = [select Phone from User where Email == email]

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach than using a trigger is to use formula fields. Those values will always be correct whatever updates or deletes are done to either `User` or `Employee__c`. (Covering all the cases requires quite a lot of trigger code.)

The (text) formulas on `Employee__c` would be `User__r.Email` for `Email_Id__c` and `User__r.Phone` for `Phone_Number__c`.

(Probably best not to include "Id" in a field name that does not hold an `ID` type value.)

**PS**

For a trigger solution, this (untested) trigger will propagate a change made on `User` to `Employee__c`:

```
trigger SyncUserToEmployee on User (after update) {

    Map<Id, User> m = the Map<Id, User>();
    for (User u : Trigger.new) {
        User old = Trigger.oldMap.get(u.Id);
        if (old.Email != u.Email || old.Phone != u.Phone) m.put(u.Id, u);
    }

    if (m.size() > 0) {
        Employee__c[] es = [
                select User__c
                from Employee__c
                where User__c in :m.keySet()
                ];
        for (Employee__c e : es) {
            User u = m.get(e.User__c);
            e.Email_Id__c = u.Email;
            e.Phone_Number__c = u.Phone;
        }
        update es;
    }
}
```

but there will also need to be a trigger on `Employee__c` to handle the initial `User__c` lookup assignment and any changes to that.

Note that this trigger is relying on the `User__c` lookup field to relate the objects not just the `Email` value.

Comment: Thanks , Keith . I am looking for applying trigger only for this functionality. If you can help with this functionality it would be great.

Comment: @Sfdcnewbie Why?

Comment: Lol.. lets say want to learn

Comment: @Sfdcnewbie I've added some trigger code.